# Conversation-like messaging system

Tags: php, mysql

I built messaging system which is something like Facebook messages. Conversations are made in one mysql table, so I have `receiverId, senderId, messageContent ...`
My problem is, I want to implement 'Delete Messages' function but I don't know how to make it, so if one member of that conversation deletes all messages, the other members should still see all messages, until the other members delete those messages as well.

So my approach (obviously wrong one) was to add additional columns: deletedByReceiver and deletedBySender, this works ok for receiver, but if sender opens those messages then he see only messages he sent because my query says: `select * from inbox where deletedByReceiver != 1`

So I don't ask for code, I ask for idea how to solve this

Comment: maybe some message_visiblilty table   message_id, user_id.   remove the user from the table when you dont want the to be able to see it.

Comment: either keep two copies of each message, one for the sender, and one for the receiver, or keep separate "deletedByX" fields, to indiciate when the sender and/or receiver have deleted it.

Comment: This is a Codeigniter library, but you can look at the sql and see how to set up your schema to handle this: http://codebyjeff.com/blog/2013/02/mahana-messaging-library  // https://github.com/jrmadsen67/Mahana-Messaging-library-for-CodeIgniter

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem right, you just need to "OR" the two sets of conditions together. The message needs to be included if either I am the sender and `deleteBySender != 1` or I am the receiver and `deleteByReceiver!=1`.

So something like:

```
SELECT * FROM inbox 
WHERE 
    (senderId = <MYID> AND deleteBySender!=1) OR 
    (receiverID = <MYID> and deleteByReceiver!=1)
```

Where, of course, `<MYID>` is replaced by the viewer's userid.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need different queries for sender and receiver:

- for the receiver (as you mentioned) `select * from inbox where deletedByReceiver != 1`
- for the sender use `select * from inbox where deletedBySender != 1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want each individual user to be able to delete the message in its own view, seems you need to add create an association table between messages and users, with `messageId, userId`. A row in the table means this message has been deleted by this user. You can also make this table more generic and have a `deleted` column (yes/no). That way you could also manage permission etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I would use a two table system, one for the messages and one for your inbox.  It will increase the size of your database, but it will allow the message to always exist, but the recipient to delete it from their view

Message Table:

> msgid* | senderId | messageContent | ts

Inbox table:

> id* | msgid_fk | recipientId

To read your messages:

> SELECT * FROM messages m JOIN inbox i ON m.msgid = i.msgid_fk WHERE recipientID = '[recipient]'

You can then create a trigger for when the sender deletes a message it also deletes it the recipient inbox.  This will also allow multiple recipients receiving the same message while storing the message once.